# SQL query need last unique value in joining

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to display the last updated value in quiz.test.program_id. How will it be possible if I remove `ORDER BY quiz_test.program_id DESC`? it shows all values but what I need to show is last updated value.

Please give me suggestions.

```
SELECT draft_business_program.program_name, draft_business_program.draft_program_id,
       draft_business_program.description, category_master.category_name
FROM draft_business_program
LEFT JOIN category_master ON draft_business_program.catgory_id = category_master.category_id 
LEFT JOIN `draft_program_recurrence` ON draft_business_program.draft_program_id  =draft_program_recurrence.draft_program_id
LEFT JOIN quiz_test ON quiz_test.program_id = draft_business_program.draft_program_id
LEFT JOIN quizmaster ON quiz_test.quiz_id = quizmaster.quiz_id
LEFT JOIN quiz_result_summary ON quiz_test.id = quiz_result_summary.quiz_test_id
LEFT JOIN business_certificates ON quiz_test.business_id = business_certificates.business_id
WHERE quiz_test.quiz_status  = 1
  AND quiz_test.user_id= 962 
  AND quiz_test.business_id= 146
ORDER BY quiz_test.program_id DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Show some sample data and expected result out of those and also the DDL.

Comment: like program_id is showing 858 three times but what i need to show it only one but last updated

Comment: Tip of today, table aliases make the code easier to read and to write!

Comment: `LIMIT 1` can't show all the data, it will only show 1 row.

Comment: I don't understand your question, so I can't answer. Why do you want to remove `ORDER BY`?

Comment: Maybe you need to order by the update time, not the program ID?

Comment: No No sorry actually when i removed order by it shows me all value but what i need last value of quiz_test.program_id

Comment: I mean in quiz_test.program_id has many program_id but i wanted to show last updated program_id

Comment: What happend Barmar m waiting any info required

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102574/discussion-between-myfirst-first-and-barmar).

Comment: I went to chat but you weren't there.

Comment: If you just want the last program ID, `ORDER BY program_id DESC LIMIT 1` should do it. I can't understand why it isn't working right for you. Can you make a sqlfiddle that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: yes but LIMIT only display one row i need all value